# Why doesn't nitrogen monoxide dimerize?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Why doesn't Nitrogen monoxide dimerize even though there is an odd electron present whereas nitrogen dioxide does (because of the odd electron on nitrogen)?

Answer (score 16):

Highstaker's answer is almost correct.  The antibonding orbitals that are occupied in NO are in fact pi symmetry, but when the dimer forms that is no longer relevant.  It is a sigma bond.

The enthalpy of the newly formed sigma bond in the dimer is weak because the net gain in bond is off set by the loss of a very odd set of single-electron resonance forms available for NO monomer.

Given $\Delta G= -17 \:\mathrm{kJ/mol}$ , and that dimerization is entropically disfavored, when the total free energy is considered there is no gain since entropic effects are on the order of $10-30 \:\mathrm{kJ/mol}$.  Thus any small gain in enthalphy is offset by the loss of entropy.

Always look at these things through Gibbs free energy and not just enthalpy.

Comment: Just to clarify, entropic effects refer to T (delta S) and not just delta S right?

Comment: Yes, the net entropic "effect" on the direction of spontaneity is indeed T*(delS), which also explains the stability of of the dimer at lower temperatures.

Answer (score 8):

Nitrogen monoxide's dimer exists, but it is very unstable. NO consists of dimeres only at low temperatures (about −163 °C). Solid NO seems to consist mostly of dimers.

Seems that unpaired electrons on antibonding orbitals can only pi-overlap. In NO the electronic density is shifted towards oxygen atom, and the "petals" of pi-orbitals don't have enough electronic density to support stable bond (some call it a half-bond). So the dimer bond is weak (enthalpy of formation is about 17 kilojoules)

Answer (score 4):

One alternative rationalisation of why the dimerisation of $\ce {NO}$ is not as favourable as that of the dimerisation of $\ce {NO2}$ is that on each of the nitrogens in the $\ce {N2O2}$ dimer, there is a lone pair while for the dimer $\ce {N2O4}$, there are no lone pairs on the nitrogens. The presence of lone pairs destabilise the nitrogen-nitrogen bond in the former, thus it decreases the enthalpic favourability of the bond formation between two $\ce {NO}$ molecules, whereas this destabilisation is not present in the latter dimer.