# Why don't unstable odd electron species dimerize so that they become stable?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, radicals

Why doesn't unstable odd electron compound $\ce{NO}$ dimerize to $\ce{N2O2}$? Why doesn't this structure of ozonide dimerize? But why then does $\ce{BH3}$ dimerizes to $\ce{B2H6}$, and $\ce{AlCl3}$ to $\ce{Al2Cl6}$, both with something like bridged bonds?

[image]

Comment: Your structure of ozone is incorrect; the positive formal charge should be on the central oxygen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't nitrogen monoxide dimerize?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4204/why-doesnt-nitrogen-monoxide-dimerize)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Odd electron species do dimerize.

> $\ce{NO}$

Nitric oxide dimerizes, but only at [low temperature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitric_oxide#Reactions) (and probably high pressure}.

> $\ce{NO2}$

Nitrogen dioxide does dimerize. In fact, this is a [well known property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_dioxide#Basic_thermal_properties) of $\ce{NO2}$. $\ce{NO2}$ (orange-brown) is in equilibrium with $\ce{N2O4}$ (colorless).

$$\ce{2NO2 <=> N2O4}$$
The position of this equilibrium is dependent on temperature and pressure (like all gas equilibria), and so it makes a nice demonstration of gas properties.

> $\ce{O3}$

Ozone does not dimerize. Dimerization would lead to $\ce{O6}$, which likely is a 6-membered ring of all oxygen atoms. While this structure violates no rules, the oxygen-oxygen single bond is not stable. This instability of the peroxide bond makes it both [useful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peroxide#Properties_and_applications_of_organic_peroxides) and [dangerous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peroxide#Safety).

> So why does $\ce{NO2}$ dimerize readily, $\ce{NO}$ dimerize under duress, and $\ce{O3}$ not dimerize at all?

The extra electron in the nitrogen oxides is found in an antibonding orbital. Conversion to the dimer gets that electron into a bonding orbital. There are no antibonding electrons in $\ce{O3}$.

> $\ce{BH3}$

Borane dimerizes because the boron atom is electron deficient - it has an empty p orbital. This species is so electron deficient that it will form bonding interactions with nearly any electron pairs, including those already in sigma bonds. (More properly the B-H-B bonds are three-center-two-electron bonds). Aluminum compounds dimerize the same way.

> So why does $\ce{BH3}$ dimerize and $\ce{O3}$ does not?

Ozone has no electron deficient atoms. Count the electrons. All atoms have an octet, and while one has a positive formal charge, the compound as a whole is not electron deficient.

Comment: Molecular oxygen is pretty stable despite its single bond.

Comment: Molecular oxygen in its ground state has a bond order of 2.

Comment: http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/@api/deki/files/4228/image017.png?revision=1

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_orbital_diagram#Dioxygen - The Lewis dot structure of $\ce{O2}$ is insufficient to represent the molecule as a diradical with bond order of 2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFuYWFWC7-w

Comment: will the edit help explain more, i edited the question too

Comment: i'm not talking about ozone, it's ozonide!

Comment: Apologies. Your structure for ozonide looks like it has a positive charge on the rightmost oxygen atom: $\ce{^{-}O-O-O+ <-> ^{-}O-O^{+}=O}$ and not a radical: $\ce{^{-}O-O-O.}$

Comment: You might include  http://pipeline.corante.com/archives/2014/10/10/things_i_wont_work_with_peroxide_peroxides.php in your useful and dangerous list.