# What is the Lewis structure of Ozonide ion?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, ozone

What will be the Lewis structure of the ozonide ion, including formal charges?

Do all oxygen atoms have filled octate?

Comment: Look at all the resonance structures of the ozone molecule to start. If you find the resonance structures of less importance, you will be able to find the structure of the ozonide ion.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20086/why-dont-unstable-odd-electron-species-dimerize-so-that-they-become-stable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a [cursory e-book search](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=L-1K9HmKmUUC&pg=PA354&lpg=PA354&dq=ozonide%20ion%20structure&source=bl&ots=zXmBZQRXr-&sig=IEQPRusbE8ZUH9RZoKSJ-lJV8Co&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjX4tTW6__YAhUdSY8KHTNmCRwQ6AEIRjAH#v=onepage&q=ozonide%20ion%20structure&f=false):

> Ozonide ion is paramagnetic and is shown to have magnetic
>   susceptibility. Bond length is 135 Å and bond angle is 108°. The
>   structure is:
>
> [image]