# Structure of N2O2

Tags: covalent-compounds, lewis-structure, nitro-compounds

I've drawn a structure of $\ce{N2O2}$ like this:

$$\ce{:\overset{\large.\!\!.}{\underset{\large.\!\!.}{O}}-N#N-\overset{\large.\!\!.}{\underset{\large.\!\!.}{O}}:}$$

I don't know if it's possible. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Also, what would be the nature of it?

Comment: The structure is wrong and what do you mean by "nature"?

Comment: I mean it's properties

Comment: Can I know why I'm wrong?

Comment: see http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4204/nitrogen-monoxide

Comment: Is you question about the nitric oxide dimer or about the hyponitrite dianion.

Comment: I don't know anything about these. I'm not an expert. I'm just a student who's practicing Lewis structures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just looking at the Lewis Structure from the perspective of the octet rule, it does *appear* that the structure is correct. Dinitrogen always has a lone pair of electrons which could conceivably be used for dative bonding as you suggest. So from that perspective there appears to be nothing wrong at all - other than that it doesn't exist in nature in this way.

If you're interested in learning about the dimer, a number of proposals have been made in this [1994 JACS paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/j100091a021). If you're interested in the hyponitrite anion, you can read about it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponitrite) (always a good place to start), and for your reference the structure of the Sodium salt is below:

[image: Sodium Hyponitrite]

Comment: The proposed structure in the original question is not really 100% correct, it is missing formal charges @VlnMurthy

Answer (score 2):

It's wrong in the sense that it is inconsistent with what is found experimentally, according to [Structure of the NO Dimer](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00381a052) J. Am. Chem. Soc., 1982, 104 (17), pp 4715–4716.

The experimental structure is cis-ONNO, with ONN angle of 99.6 degrees.

The N-N bond length is 2.236 Angstroms, while the N-O bond lengths are 1.161 Angstroms.

No single Lewis structure can accurately describe the electronic state of this molecule; however, considering the bond lengths, a single N-N bond and triple N-O bonds would be better.

See [The 16 valence electronic states of nitric oxide dimer](http://uregina.ca/~eastalla/ONNOelec.pdf) form more information.